# Expect - avoid sending escape prompt sequences via ssh

Tags: tcl, command-prompt, expect

The script is intended to retrieve the contents of some directory when it is getting full.

For development, the 'full' was set at 15%, the directory is `/var/crash`.

```
expect "#*" {
    foreach part $full {
        puts "part: $part"
        set dir [split $part]
        puts "dir: $dir [llength $dir]"
        set d [lindex $dir 0]
        puts "d: $d"
        send -s -- "ls -lhS $d\n"
        expect "#*" { puts "for $dir :: $expect_out(buffer)"}
    }
}
send "exit\r"
```

The output of the script is:

```
part: /var/crash 15%
dir: {/var/crash} 15% 2
d: /var/crash
send: sending "ls -lhS \u001b[01;31m\u001b[K/var\u001b[m\u001b[K/crash\n" to { exp7 }
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "#*"? no
expect: does "ls -lhS \u00071;31m\u0007/var\u0007\u0007/" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "#*"? no
expect: does "ls -lhS \u00071;31m\u0007/var\u0007\u0007/crash\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "#*"? no
```

As can be seen, although `$d` is `/var/crash`, when it is sent via ssh it becomes something like `\u001b[01;31m\u001b[K/var\u001b[m\u001b[K/crash`.

I cannot change the remote machine definitions for the command prompt.

How to get rid of these escape sequences that are sent?

Edit: Info about `$full` as requested

The `proc` analyze just tries to filter meaningful data.

```
proc analyze_df {cmd txt} {
    set full [list]
    set lines [split $txt \n]
    foreach l $lines {
        if {[string match $cmd* $l]} { continue }
        set lcompact [regsub -all {\s+} $l " "]
        set data [split $lcompact]
        if {[string match 8?% [lindex $data 4]] \
            || [string match 9?% [lindex $data 4]] \
            || [string match 1??% [lindex $data 4]] \
            || [string match 5?% [lindex $data 4]] \
            || [string match 1?% [lindex $data 4]] } {
            lappend full "[lindex $data 5] [lindex $data 4]"
        }
    }
    return $full
}
```

The extract about the `$full` that was missing.

```
set command0 "df -h | grep /var"
send -- "$pass\r"
expect {
    -nocase "denied*" {puts "$host denied"; continue}
    -nocase "Authentication failed*" {puts "$host authentication failed"; continue}
    "$*" {send -s -- "$command0\n"}
    timeout {puts "$host TIMEOUT"; continue}
}
expect "$*" {puts "$host -> $expect_out(buffer)" }
set full [analyze_df $command0 $expect_out(buffer)]
```

Taking the suggestion received, perhaps it's `grep` that is adding the escape sequences, no?

Comment: please post how you get `$full`.

Comment: After changing the command from `df -h | grep /var` to `df -h | grep --color=never /var`, the escape sequences are no longer present.  But setting the terminal environment seems like a better solution.

Comment: Note you _can_ change the prompt for the duration of the ssh session (not permanently): `spawn ssh ...` then assuming the remote shell is bash: `send -- "unset PROMPT_COMMAND; PS1='> '\r"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show how `$full` gets its value. But it must already have the escape codes. When printing `$d` those escape codes are interpreted by the terminal, so they may not be obvious. But Expect/Tcl definitely doesn't insert them. This is also confirmed by the braces around the first element when you print `$dir`. If this element was plain `/var/crash`, there would be no braces.

Your remark about the command prompt would suggest that `$full` may be taken from there. Maybe you cannot permanently change the remote machine's command prompt, but you should be able to change it for your session by setting the PS1 environment variable.

Another trick that may help in such situations is to do `set env(TERM) dumb` before spawning the `ssh` command. If the prompt (or other tools) correctly use the `tput` command to generate their escape codes, a dumb terminal will result in empty strings. This won't work if the escape codes are hard-coded for one specific TERM. But that's a bug on the remote side.

Comment: It worked, thank you.  I haven't yet finish to read the Exploring Expect book...

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely stuck with that input data (and can't tell things to not mangle it with those ANSI terminal colour escape codes) then you can strip them out with:

```
set dir [split [regsub -all {\u001b[^a-zA-z]*[a-zA-Z]} $part ""]]
```

This makes use of the fact that the escape sequences start with the escape character (encoded as `\u001b`) and continue to the first ASCII letter. Replacing them all with the empty string should de-fang them cleanly.

---

You are recommended to try things like altering the `TERM` environment variable *before calling `spawn`* so that you don't have to do such cleaning. That tends to be easier than attempting to "clean up" the data after the fact.

Comment: Great to know this, it may be useful someday, as setting the terminal to dumb seems the best solution.  Thank you very much.